# How to save user input to a variable in tcl. I can't get it to work

Tags: variables, textbox, tcl, user-input, tk-toolkit

I am incredibly new at this!

I am using tcl/tk and would like to let the user put in a new "name". The new name should be stored in the variable "name" but I get an error message (unknown variable). $name doesn't seem to contain the user input. Can you see what I have done wrong?

```
entry .editname.newname -textvar name
pack .editname.newname

button .editname.save -text "Save" -command "
    set character($id,1) $name
    destroy .editname
"
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your code. This code works and hopefully does what you intended:

```
set id foo

frame .editname
pack .editname

entry .editname.newname -textvar name
pack .editname.newname

button .editname.save -text "Save" -command [list saveName $id]
pack .editname.save

proc saveName {id} {
    set ::character($id,1) $::name
    destroy .editname.newname
}
```

One of the problems was that the window path `.editname` wasn't defined (maybe it was defined in code you didn't copy?). I fixed that by adding a frame with that name. BTW, did you intend to just destroy the entry widget in the command, leaving the button and the rest of the window?

Another problem was that you tried to define a command on the `button` command line. That's rarely a good idea, unless it's a *really* short and sweet command. It's a better idea to define a command, like `saveName` here, and refer to it by name on the `button` command line.

However, the variable `name` exists in the global scope and is invisible inside the `saveName` command. We solve that by adding a double colon to the variable name inside the `proc` to tell Tcl to look it up in the global scope. The variable called `character` also needs a double colon. The variable `id` could also be global, but for variety we might want to pass its value to the `saveName` command as an argument.

When just passing a command without arguments to a command option to, say, a button, we just need to mention the name:

```
... -command myCmd
```

but if we want to pass arguments to it when the button activates it, we need to set the command option to a list (or a string with spaces, which in Tcl is pretty much the same thing):

```
... -command {myCmd foo bar}
```

but if the values we want to pass to the command are inside variables or are produced by commands, we need to write them like this:

```
... -command [list myCmd $myVar [myOtherCmd foo bar]]
```

remembering that the arguments will be snapshots of those values at the time the command option is set, not the time the button (or whatever) is pressed and the command activated.

This brings us back to what might have been your basic problem: you assigned the value of `name` to a member of `character` *at the point where the button was created*, which means that you hadn't yet written anything in the entry and so the variable didn't exist yet. And, even if the variable had been set, clicking the button wouldn't have done anything, it just assigned the value of the variable at the time of button creation to the array once more.

Defined like above, if you change the value of the `name` variable (which you'll have to do by hand, since you just destroyed the entry widget) and click the button again, the contents of `character($id,1)` are changed.

Comment: I am incredibly gratefull for your answer! Not only did you take the time for it, you clarified several things for me that I was still pondering! In addition, your code works and solved my problem!! :)

Comment: @user3356752: no prob. If you found the answer useful, you might want to click the check mark to accept the answer.